# Pass Element Id from file to another filer Revit Api c#

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm trying to make copy from family file contain Extrusion (the Element i want to select ) and make  copy of it in another file "I mean there is two opened files where i select the element from the family file and paste it in another project file ".
So the Question: **how to transfer the Element Id and location data from file to file in c#?**

i tried to load the family in the project i work on but nothing appears .
So any Guidlines how to do that?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is a really poorly formulated question. Please attach some code that you tried and perhaps re-write the question. I cannot make out what you asking for. Is it how to copy element from one file to another? Is it how to load a family into a model?

Answer (score 0):

The element id will always be different in the second file.

You need to create a new instance of the element type using the appropriate

```
Autodesk.Revit.Creation.Document.NewFamilyInstance(...)
```

depending on the type of instance you are trying to create.